# vis.js Chronological set of items in Timeline View

Tags: vis.js-timeline

Instead of having actual time mapping with the items in Timeline View, is there a way by which we can have items arranged chronologically in sequence of timestamps. This feature will help me eliminate gaps between items with greater timestamp difference.

For Example 
E1: 1 
E2: 6
E3: 9

Current Timeline View would represent it as

[1 - E1] 2 3 4 5 [6 - E2] 7 8 [9 - E3]

What I want is chronological order

[1 - E1] [2 - E2] [3 - E3]

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve what you are asking for by using the hiddenDates option of the timeline

```js
{
 "option": "hiddenDates",
 "type": "object|Array",
 "default": "none",
 "description": "This option allows you to hide specific timespans from the time axis. The dates can be supplied as an object: {start: '2014-03-21 00:00:00', end: '2014-03-28 00:00:00', [repeat:'daily']} or as an Array of these objects. The repeat argument is optional. The possible values are (case-sensitive): daily, weekly, monthly, yearly. To hide a weekend, pick any Saturday as start and the following Monday as end and set repeat to weekly."
}
```

In your case you can specify hiddenDates as

```js
var options = {hiddenDates: [{start: '2', end:'6'},{start:'7',end: '9'}]}
```

If this doesn't answer your question, I can provide a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) with a solution.

Best regards,
Betim.